# flutter daemon terminated when I try to launch my app

Tags: flutter

Just upgraded to v1.1.8 for flutter. Restarted Android studio. Using an emulator. Drop down menu for devices has disappeared and the AVD manager has been greyed out.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason Intellij IDEA did the same thing for me today. It suggested restarting IDE, but that did not work. Nonetheless restarting PC solved it.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to kill the adb.exe processes in the Task Manager. There were 20 of them and once I killed them all everything started working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the flutter folder by mistake. Re-cloning it back and restarting flutter worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try removing/commenting the settings from `.vscode/settings.json` like example below:

```
{
    "xd.globalEditor": false,
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    // "dart.flutterTestAdditionalArgs": ["--no-sound-null-safety"],
    // "dart.flutterAdditionalArgs": ["--no-sound-null-safety"],
    // "dart.vmAdditionalArgs": ["--no-sound-null-safety"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a permission issue. If just in case you're using VSCode then it always tries to search for the devices without sudo command. Check if your flutter command can run without attaching sudo to it (`sudo flutter`). If it throws some error then there's a permission issue. To solve this, you will need to reinstall the flutter in the low secured directory like `/usr` etc. Or just change the folder permissions where you have installed the flutter.

Hope this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was my firewall, I was using the COMODO firewall and it was blocking the Flutter Daemon so I just uninstall it and the problem is solved.
you can check this article for more solutions => https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-unable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a VPN running in the background. When i disconnected the VPN, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

A few things to try:

1. Restart VS Code (if you didn't try already). The daemon terminating is not unusual when you upgrade (there's an issue about improving this at Recover from Flutter daemon quitting (eg. during flutter upgrade) Dart-Code/Dart-Code#931).
2. Check whether flutter doctor works from the terminal (if there's something wrong with Flutter after the upgrade, it may affect launching the daemon)
3. If after restarting VS Code you're still seeing this message, enable Flutter Daemon Logging, restart VS Code to reproduce the issue, then send me the log.

On Ubuntu 20.04, adb 33.0. 1, Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1. 1: Android Studio > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger: Set "Use existing manually managed server" with port 5038.

For more details, visit [The Flutter daemon has been terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67353667/)