# Error: "Unable to run adb check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: E:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Tags: android, flutter, adb

### Brief

I am new to Flutter. I installed Android Studio and Flutter source code as mentioned in Flutter's [Installation guide for windows](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows). I had a problem with the lack of storage space on `C:Drive` as mentioned in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030571/how-to-install-android-studio-2020-3-1-for-windows-64-bit-completely-on-a-drive), so I installed Android Studio entirely on my `E:Drive` using Jet Brains ToolBox instead of breaking my head with symbolic links for everything, following the answer of the previous question, but I ran into another problem after having everything on my `E:Drive`, whenever I try to run an Android Virtual Device or run `flutter doctor -v` , I get the following error:

### Error Message

```js
Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
    X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    X Exception: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: E:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
    • #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
      #1      AndroidDevices.pollingGetDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device_discovery.dart:75:7)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #2      PollingDeviceDiscovery._populateDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:413:54)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #3      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #4      DeviceManager.getAllConnectedDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:170:40)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #5      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:515:34)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #6      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:24)
      <asynchronous suspension>
```

I also tried to use VS Code with the flutter-dart extension but I keep getting the message `Flutter daemon has terminated`.

When I tried to run the adb server manually, I keep getting the following error

```js
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

So I even tried to kill the server and got the following error

```js
cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

### Little More Info

I have the following folders at these locations:

| Folder | Location |
| --- | --- |
| `Android Studio` | E:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio |
| `Flutter` | D:{user}\Documents_HDD\Programming\Flutter\flutter |
| `Android Sdk` | E:\Android\Sdk |
| `.android` | E:\Android.android |

**Also** the `.android` folder was stored in `AppData\Local` but I observed that flutter tried to create another `.android` folder inside the Sdk folder and that caused an error stating `avd` path is broken, so I moved the .android folder into Sdk folder.

I have been facing this issue for a few months now. I have searched the net for some solutions but none of them has worked. I tried the following

- Adding the environment variables `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, `ANDROID_AVD_HOME`, `ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT` and path variables to `platform-tools` and `tools` folders present in the Sdk folder
- Allowing `adb.exe` through the firewall and antivirus program.
- I even checked if there is any other program running at `tcp:5037` port but there was no program using that port.

None of these solutions worked. Can someone please help me with this problem?
I want adb to work properly for flutter development.

If any further information is required, please let me know in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: you can try  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54483617/10157127) or how about reinstalling everything

Comment: I tried reinstalling but it did not work.

Comment: I will try to change the flutter folder. Could you please explain to me where I must create that `/usr` folder?

Comment: you dont need to create `/usr`  folder, it is already in your computer,you can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

Comment: I have very less space on my `C:` drive, so can I put flutter in `E:\Users\usr` ?

Comment: ok then set env to e